# Capturing digital TV and stream it on local network

Tags: c#, video-streaming, rtsp, directshow.net

I need to capture digital TV signals and stream the TV channels on the local network (via Http, RTSP or any protocol like this). I'm using [CodeTV](https://github.com/dgis/CodeTV) to find TV channels, capture and decode them. The project uses DirectShow.Net to do that. I found [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) helpful to stream data on the local network. The problem is, I'm not familiar with Directshow and I can't figure it out how to get the video stream and give it to the Vlc library.
I tried to replace this code with the code that records the video stream but "bs" remains null.

```
IStream bs = this.currentGraphBuilder as IStream;
var currentDirectory = 
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
currentDirectory = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc");
var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, 
IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
using (Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new 
Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
{
    var mediaOptions = new[]
    {
        ":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/}",
        ":sout-keep"
    };
    mediaPlayer.SetMedia(bs as Stream, mediaOptions);
    mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

I don't know if I need to create a filter and add it to the graph or there is a simpler way.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52881707/edit) your question to include code you have already tried.

Comment: @Ruzihm Hi and thanks for the reply. I added some code that didn't work (obviously). If I could have a stream and give it to the SetMedia, the problem would be solved.